# Python regex: exclude \r\n

Tags: python, regex, string

I am trying to get the letters and white spaces out of a string but it keeps `\r\n` which I don't want in the results. Also is there a function that returns the results excluding the regex I give it?

---

My code that needs to exclude `\r\n`

```
region = ",,,Central California\r\n"

#\w Matches word characters.
#\s Matches whitespace
print re.findall(r"[\w\s]+", region)
```

---

excepted output `['Central California']`

output got `['Central California\r\n']`

---

Return everything that doesn't match the regex

```
region = ",,,Central California\r\n"

#\W Matches nonword characters.
print re.exclude_function(r"[\W]+", region)
```

---

excepted output `['Central California']`

---

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me you are parsing a csv file. you should consider using the [built-in Python library](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) for that.

To remove trailing newlines, you can use [str.srip()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip).

If you want to capture everything in every segment, you can do something much simpler than that:

```
re.findall(r',?([^,]+)(?:,|\r\n)', string)
# this regex captures anything between `,` and/or a newline
```

Showing it with your string:

```
>>> s = ",,,Central California\r\n"
>>> re.findall(r',?([^,]+)(?:,|\r\n)', s)
['Central California']
```

With multiple items:

```
>>> s = ",itemA,itemB,Central California\r\n"
>>> re.findall(r',?([^,]+)(?:,|\r\n)', s)
['itemA', 'itemB', 'Central California']

>>> s = "BASE,itemA,itemB,Central California\r\n"
>>> re.findall(r',?([^,]+)(?:,|\r\n)', s)
['BASE', 'itemA', 'itemB', 'Central California']
```

Comment: if you are using a CSV file, pythons builtin library is better suited to handle your needs than regular expressions. take a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

`\s` contains `\r` and `\n`, so just use

```
re.findall(r"[\w\t ]+", region)
```

instead (`"\t"` being the tab character and `" "` being, well, space).

And if you want a function to return everything that didn't match your regex, simply do a replace-all on it:

```
def exclude_function(regex, string):
    return re.sub(regex, "", string)
```

Comment: thanks, I using a function to just go through a string and replace everything I didn't want with "", So this helps a lot. regex sure does save a lot of coding.